# Avoid white vertical line on the left side of mobile version

Tags: html, css

The mobile version of my website displays an annoyed white vertical line on the left side (see below).

[image]

To see it on my desktop computer, I used Google Chrome, then I open the console (F12) then I click on the `mobile` icon on the left side.

[image]

Thanks for your help !!

See it here (on mobile) : http://azurconsult.wix.com/test1

Comment: If you click the "magnifier" icon right next to the mobile icon and hover over the white line, you should be able to see what element it is part of on the right

Comment: Ik know about this `magnifier` but this vertical white line is not foundable, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an unintentional margin pushing it over.  Best thing to do is to pull smaller hunks of HTML then render and repeat untill the line goes away then  you know where to start your repairs.  I would first look at margins and padding.

Please post some code.

Comment: the code is available online at the address showed in the screenshot above. I already try to play with margins but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in viewer.css at line 89:

```
background-color: rgb(84, 77, 12);
```

In this way you set a background-color for the mobile version. Probably we see a white line because width, margin or padding are not fixed somewhere

Comment: This is not bad but not applicable everywhere. I mean on another website I have different colors on different (vertical) bands (full width), you know what I mean? So I cannot define a unique background-color to fix it. Thanks anyway.